# How to get array result from Oracle stored procedure

Tags: php, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to find this on internet but I can find it anywhere.
I want to have Oracle stored procedure something like :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Read()
IS
   BEGIN
         SELECT * FROM Books;   
   END;
/
```

that will get me as result and array. So I want to retrieve in PHP array result of this oracle stored procedure. Can you please modify it?
So when I get array in php I can easily fetch through the data?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you don't want to return an array.  Instead, I suspect that you want your stored procedure to return a `REF CURSOR`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Read( p_rc OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_rc
   FOR SELECT *
         FROM books;
END;
```

If you really want to return an array from PL/SQL (which is going to use vastly more PGA space on the server among other resources), you could do

```
CREATE TYPE book_typ 
    AS OBJECT (
  <<list of columns in BOOKS>>
);

CREATE TYPE book_tbl 
    AS TABLE OF book_typ;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Read( p_arr OUT book_tbl )
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT <<list of columns>>
     BULK COLLECT INTO p_arr
     FROM books;
END;
```

It would almost never make sense to structure code this way rather than returning a `REF CURSOR`.  It will be much less efficient, use vastly more server resources making it much less scalable, etc.  Additionally, there are a variety of ways to generate XML directly in PL/SQL.

Comment: Problem is I really want to return an array because I have class for reading array and transforming it to an XML, I have seen this for cursor thing. Is it possible to do this for an array instead of cursor?

Comment: @Denmonth - I expanded my answer to include an approach that has a PL/SQL array as an out parameter.

Comment: thank you sir, I will try this tomorrow it's ttoo late right now. I'll mark it as answered!

Comment: Is it possible to return cursor (I am getting error around `OPEN p_rc AS` to be more specific arount AS statement it says it's expecting .( or something like that and then transform cursor into array of data? So I don't waste a lot of resources? And this `<<list of columns in BOOKS>>` you mean I just put all columns separated. with ,? Thank you

Comment: @Denonth - Apologies, there was a syntax error in the code I posted.  It should have been a `FOR` not an `AS` in the `OPEN`.  I corrected that.